# How do I resolve a 404 error with Telerik WebResource.axd file?

Tags: css, asp.net, iis-7, telerik, webresource.axd

We have two identical web servers, one for test, one for production.  We just moved an asp.net site onto the production.  We have several Telerik controls including a set of RadButtons using the style WebBlue.  On the test server, these buttons are formatted with a border around them and a blue background.  However, on the production server, the buttons showing without the border or background color.  Using the developer console in Chrome, we can see the error is a 404 error for WebResource.axd.  This seems to be a Telerik style sheet.  We've checked and both sites have the same files.  This includes the bin folder containing the Telerik references and the web.config with Telerik and WebResource defined.  We even directly copied all the code from one server to another and still there's this missing reference to WebResource.axd.  Searching online leads to suggestions like IIS is set up to handle axd files and the web.config being incorrect.  I've checked and the handling and web.config are identical.  I even saw a suggestion to manually create the axd file that I tried without success (I went to testsite.com/WebResource.axd, copied what came up--code for a stylesheet--into a file called WebResource.axd, and copied with to the live server).  We put a ticket into Telerik and they answered something about problems transferring a site from asp.net to asp.net MVC (which is NOT something we're doing).  We've responded telling them this isn't a part of our issue, but we're stuck waiting on them and need to get this site up.  Our thoughts now are that something with Telerik is missing from the production server (something outside the project folder, like in a Program Files or Windows folder) or that something in IIS is preventing axd files from being used.  Does anyone out there with Telerik in IIS recognize this problem?  How do we resolve it?

Here is the test site where the buttons are rendered correctly:
[image]

Here is the production site where the buttons are not rendered correctly:
[image]

Here is the error we're getting the production site:
[image]

Here is the text of the error if that picture is too small:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   https://productionserver.com/WebResource.axd?d=dQ7gIaUlai3Z6U6rB3cRtOju4Bf1ReI3NFQN1mDwBRI0Q8BgW2h0xmppfMvidQSupNjZstrIfis4ClWbr3HyGn8paOvGU-zyEe2WESslWKjab9mEEnnjb-TympWmJzzpblolb7WlI-6yfnyWTQfAcQ0r7_q2C0pbHfF8BVnib-I1&t=635416927080000000

Here is the handler mapping in IIS showing that axd files are set up:
[image]

Here are the sections of the web.config that refer to Telerik and the WebResource.axd file:

```
<httpHandlers>
    <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource, Telerik.Web.UI, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" validate="false" />
    <add path="ChartImage.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
    <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
    <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
    <add path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadProgressHandler" verb="*" validate="false" />
    <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" validate="false" />
</httpHandlers>

<handlers>
  <remove name="ChartImage_axd" />
  <add name="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" verb="*"    type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource, Telerik.Web.UI, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4"/>
  <add name="ChartImage_axd" path="ChartImage.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
  <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_SpellCheckHandler_axd" />
  <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_SpellCheckHandler_axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
  <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx" />
  <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx" path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
  <remove name="Telerik_RadUploadProgressHandler_ashx" />
  <add name="Telerik_RadUploadProgressHandler_ashx" path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadProgressHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
  <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" />
  <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
</handlers>
```

*** Update 1 ***
Found some more information that might be useful.  The line that references WebResource.axd is:

```
 <link class='Telerik_stylesheet' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='/WebResource.axd?d=oX7CVk8ieCqIm63GoqTn4pmChsM38l8-CqErNwBJK8bndDqbHfRL40riATcdts1t9WiNUwUdjINvesIa4uZisbBNhlldez1zIrFgnbzURY14adI59cmhQIUPb-zfBWhYQZrZZY8a1gGIfBfyuWSR6w2&amp;t=635416927080000000' /><link class='Telerik_stylesheet' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='/WebResource.axd?d=dQ7gIaUlai3Z6U6rB3cRtOju4Bf1ReI3NFQN1mDwBRI0Q8BgW2h0xmppfMvidQSupNjZstrIfis4ClWbr3HyGn8paOvGU-zyEe2WESslWKjab9mEEnnjb-TympWmJzzpblolb7WlI-6yfnyWTQfAcQ0r7_q2C0pbHfF8BVnib-I1&amp;t=635416927080000000' />
```

On the test site (where it's working) it references http://testsite.com/WebResource.axd....

On the production site, this is where the 404 error comes in.